# Do I need to disable access to HDD where does windows live when using Ubuntu installed on SSD?

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, ssd

I'm afraid to harm data on HDD. Are my concerns justified? If yes, how to fix it.

Comment: Can you rephrase this for more clarity?  It's hard to understand what you're asking

Answer (score 0):

Linux will not generally do anything to a disk that is not used.
So the Windows disk may only be damaged by user mistake.

If you wish to even avoid this possibility, you may disable the mounting of the
Windows disk, this way
([source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124094/how-to-hide-an-ntfs-partition-from-ubuntu))
in Ubuntu:

1. Hit the super/windows key
2. Type and open `disks`
3. Select the partition you want to hide so it becomes orange
4. select the cog/settings/advanced settings icon.  Click *Edit Mount Options*
5. Turn *auto mount* off
6. Uncheck both *Mount at Startup* and *Show in user interface*
7. Save & Reboot

The
[source link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124094/how-to-hide-an-ntfs-partition-from-ubuntu)
contains more methods, but more complicated.